# Kubernetes apache pod keeps restarting

Tags: apache-2.4, kubernetes

So I'm really new to kubernetes and I'm having this problem where the pods keep restarting. I've googled around a bit but not coming up with much help. All I have is a simple apache deployment, nothing fancy.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: website-deployment
  labels:
    app: website
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: website
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: website
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: apache
        image: httpd:2.4.57
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Here is the log from the pod

```
root@kubemaster:~# kubectl logs website-deployment-cc57f5644-2kg7v -p
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.240.0.110. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.240.0.110. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Mon Apr 10 19:16:24.132794 2023] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1:tid 140595614588224] AH00489: Apache/2.4.57 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Apr 10 19:16:24.133016 2023] [core:notice] [pid 1:tid 140595614588224] AH00094: Command line: 'httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Mon Apr 10 19:22:42.890545 2023] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1:tid 140595614588224] AH00492: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
```

As you can see it runs for a few minutes before getting a SIGWINCH event and this triggers the pod to go into CrashLoopBackOff before starting back up again. This then keeps happening in a loop.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 for the master and I have 2 Ubuntu 22.04 for the nodes.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Ashley welcome to S.F. It looks, based solely upon that pasted snippet, that you are trying to run Apache without any configuration whatsoever, which is a fine reason why it doesn't produce any meaningful logs and cheerfully just dies. Also, running `:latest` is a great way to generate bugs, since we have no idea what version of the container you're running. Try picking one of [the known versions](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/tags) so at least everyone is operating with the same mental model. Good luck

Comment: I've changed the config to use version "2.4.57" this results in the same behaviour. I understand I've not done any configuration of apache myself but surely out of the box it should work fine

Comment: Well, that's why I said based solely upon the pasted snippet. If you run `docker run -p 80:80 httpd:2.4.57` locally, what behavior do you get?

Comment: Running using docker manually works perfect, no issues. Just a side note I've noticed that the kube-flannel and kube-proxy pods keep restarting also. Not sure if it's related